# what is the role of granulation tissue in bone fracture repair

Tags: bone-biology, tissue-repair

When a bone fractures, let's say with a large enough gap that repair has to occur through secondary healing, vessel rupture will result in a hemorrhage that then coagulates, there's inflammation that removes tissue debris, and granulation tissue forms as capillaries and fibroblasts infiltrate, using the hematoma as scaffolding. Next is the formation of the soft callus. What is the composition of this soft callus?

I understand that chondroblast precursors are activated, and cartilage forms to bridge the fracture ends, but what happens to the granulation tissue from earlier? The fibroblasts that infiltrated the site of the fracture, do they lay down fibrous connective tissue or do they differentiate into cartilage cells and lay down cartilage matrix as well? I've been reading from multiple sources, and none of them really specify it well enough for the ambiguity to not remain.